# MVC 4 web application shows html encode text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, globalization

I'm using resources files to show localized version of a web application.

```
<h1>@Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(MasterPage_master.lblHowToGet_Text), "HowToGet", "Home")</h1>
```

However, the output shows "Lage & a m p; Anfahrt" (spaces added to stopt SO showing the ampersand char) while the text in resource file is "Lage & Anfahrt". If I store the text encoded in the resource file the text is also showing the & value.

What is the correct way to store this data in resource files and output it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just non-html text and prefer to have them html encoded, use the below line:

```
// If MasterPage_master.lblHowToGet_Text = "Lage & Anfahrt"
<h1>@Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(Html.Raw(MasterPage_master.lblHowToGet_Text)), "HowToGet", "Home")</h1>
```

But if your resource properties contains html tags, do not Html encode the text and use as below:

```
// If MasterPage_master.lblHowToGet_Text = "Lage & Anfahrt <br /> Some other text"
<h1>@Html.ActionLink(Html.Raw(MasterPage_master.lblHowToGet_Text), "HowToGet", "Home")</h1>
```

Comment: And then should I store the text already html encoded in my resource files? It's not posible to have mvc to do this for me at runtime?

Comment: The resource properties shouldn't necessarily be stored html encoded but when you do a Html.Raw, it would not html encode it by default but will be display accurately. But if you prefer the content to be html encoded, just Html.Encode the Html.Raw content. Keep in mind that if you have any html inside the content, you should not Html encode it as it would  display the br tag as &lt;br /&gt; See the updated answer.

Comment: I have "Lage & Anfahrt" in the resource file, and the page source is showing the same value, not encoded. It should be "&amp;" in source code, and shown as "&", but I can't get it to work. None of the two examples is doing it. :-(